# Changing an #VALUE! in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet and an apps script that I am working on, but I am running into an issue within it. I have two columns on one sheet, B and C that contain various values.  B will contain the word Middle, and C will be the actual data that I need.

I use a formula in column G, that read the values from columns B, and C and pull out the relevant data that matches 'Middle'  It puts anything that matches Middle in column G and puts the data from column C in the adjoining H cell.  The formula that I am using for column G looks like this.

```
=IF (ISERROR(QUERY('Announcements'!B2:C30;"select * where B contains 'Middle'")), "", QUERY('Announcements'!B2:C30;"select * where B contains 'Middle'"))
```

and then column H which contains this:

```
=CONTINUE(G2, 1, 2)
```

When the sheet formula runs, it pulls the correct data, but the issue that I am running into is that if there isn't any data to pull that matches the criteria (Middle), then the H2 cell gets a **-** in it, and the app-script throws a **#VALUE!** into the google doc that it is populating when it runs.

The app-script currently looks like this:

```
var sh10 = sh2.getRange('H2:H20').getValues(); //Middle
```

I have tried modifying this code that I found

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Announcements")
var active = sheet.getActiveCell('H2');
var cell = active.getValue();
if (cell === "#VALUE!"){
active.setValue("");
};
```

But when I run the script, I get the error message of **"Cannot find method getActiveCell(string). (line 64, file "Test"**

My end goal is to be able to have the sheet and script run, and and if there isn't any data to insert in the place holder for the doc, just put a blank space in that particular place holder and move on to the next part.  These are the parts where the script counts the total number of matches to Middle and inserts the data into the place holder

```
var sh21 = sh2.getRange(3,12).getValue(); // Middle
var announcement2 = ""; for (var i = 0; i <= 20 - sh21; i++) { announcement2 += sh10[i]+"\n"; } // Middle
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: The question is not clearly explained, however as per my understanding what you wanted to implement is -- 1. Clear the contents in Col-G and Col-H. Add the formula for Column G and the to H. 2. You wanted to find if the B and C columns contains "Middle", so you can add the string to Col G and a count value Col H.3. Do you want to implement this in Apps script function? Confirm and edit the question in clear way.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have a variable named `ss`, but I don't see a line of code getting a reference to the spreadsheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

If you don't have that line, then the next few lines of code that depend on `ss` won't work.

If you put in a `Logger.log()` statement to check your variable, you can see what the variable is being set to:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log("The value of my ss variable: " + ss);

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Announcements")
Logger.log("sheet variable: " + sheet);
```

Then VIEW the LOG after the code has run.
I'm guessing the sheet is probably null, and that is causing the error.

I'm not saying that this answers your question, but to debug the problem, we have to systematically go through a process.

Comment: Hi,

My apologies.  I do have the var ss line in the code.  It was higher up and I forgot to include it.  Here is the Logger code that you suggested, and this is what came back.

The value of my ss variable: Spreadsheet
sheet variable: Sheet

I believe that the issue stems from how I am trying to get the value of only one of the cells.  In one part of the code, I am asking it to get the values of the range of H2 - H20, which gives me this:

    #VALUE!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

After that, I ask it get the active cell H2 and get the value of that. If that cell matches #VALUE! then set the value as “”

Answer (score 0):

The method .getActiveCell() returns whatever the active cell is in the spreadsheet (let's say the currently selected cell). If you want the value of 'H2', you'll need a different method: getRange('H2').getValue().

[Documentation getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell())

Comment: Hi.  Season's Greetings.  I ran the code as you suggested, and it came back with "This is the value of H2: #VALUE!", which is what I expected.  Is there a way to manipulate that so that instead of that, it turns the value into " "?  Thank you,  Paul